# ElasticSearch 6.3.2 Could not create JVM when start

Tags: elasticsearch

I have just installed elastic search 6.3.2 on my win 10 pc from msi package. But when I tried to start the elasticsearch.exe in the command line, I was promted some issues related to JVM version.

The error messages are:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m'
[0.003sError: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
]Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

[error][logging                  ] [] Error opening log file 'logs/gc.log': No such file or directory
```

I found there is a similar issue: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/setting-up-elasticsearch-6-0-1/111280

But it is said that elastic 6.0+ could support java 10. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html )

Also I have tried to download the zip installation package. When run the elasticsearch.bat, I also got the deprecated warning message, but the engine is started successfully.

```
D:\Software\elasticsearch-6.3.2\bin>elasticsearch.bat
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[2018-08-17T16:55:29,761][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ZHUZIXIAO-IBM] initializing ...
[2018-08-17T16:55:29,828][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ZHUZIXIAO-IBM] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Windows (C:)]], net usable_space [8.2gb], net total_space [80gb], types [NTFS]
[2018-08-17T16:55:29,829][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ZHUZIXIAO-IBM] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
```

It seems a little awkard to me. Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks very much!

=======

**Update:**

ElasticSearch can run properly after I installed java 8u181. So is it still a version incompatible issue?

Comment: I have the same log error, running ElasticSearch 6.2.4 and JVM 1.8.0_192